# Filter Pattern with generic TypeOf

Tags: c#, generics, software-design

I'm implementing the filter (criteria) pattern and I'm not sure what the best approach is to create a generic TypeOfCriteria.

To give some context, part of the filtering system is specific, for example I have an EmailAddressContains filter inside a UserCriteria folder. The user class is abstract and there are several different usertypes inheriting from that base class, for example AdminUser and FullControlUser. Other parts of the system have similar inheritance trees. At first I implemented specific TypeOf criteria like TypeOfAdminUser, but I soon figured I could make this more generic.

I came up with three approaches and I'm not sure which is "the best". Or perhaps there's another approach which I haven't thought of yet.

**Approach 1**

```
public interface ICriteria<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> MeetCriteria(IEnumerable<T> entities);
}

public class TypeOfCriteria<T> : ICriteria<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly Type _type;

    public TypeOfCriteria(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> MeetCriteria(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        return from T entity in entities
               where entity.GetType().Equals(_type)
               select entity;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ICriteria<User> criteria = new TypeOfCriteria<User>(typeof(AdminUser));
admins = criteria.MeetCriteria(users);
```

**Approach 2**

```
public interface ICriteria<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> MeetCriteria(IEnumerable<T> entities);
}

public class TypeOfCriteria<T, TResult> : ICriteria<T>
    where T : BaseEntity
    where TResult : BaseEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<T> MeetCriteria(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        return entities.OfType<TResult>().Cast<T>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ICriteria<User> criteria = new TypeOfCriteria<User, AdminUser>();
admins = criteria.MeetCriteria(users);
```

**Approach 3**

```
public interface ICriteria<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> MeetCriteria<TResult>(IEnumerable<T> entities);
}

public class TypeOfCriteria<T> : ICriteria<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<T> MeetCriteria<TResult>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        return entities.OfType<TResult>().Cast<T>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ICriteria<User> criteria = new TypeOfCriteria<User>();
admins = criteria.MeetCriteria<AdminUser>(users);
```

**Pros & Cons**

Approach 1 feels the most like my other Criteria classes, where I pass the actual criteria in the constructor (new EmailAddressContains(".com")).

The MeetCriteria implementation of Approach 2 feels a bit cleaner. I'm not sure about performance, this looks like it could be faster, but that's not really a metric that I worry about for this project.

I like Approach 3 the least, because it requires me to change the interface.

Comment: Its worth noting that method 1 can give different results to the other two. OfType will not just match on exact type but also match anything derived from its type. So for example if I do `.OfType<Base>()` that will return all types that are `Base` or are derived from `Base`. This may not be relevant in your specific case but it is worth keeping in mind.

Comment: What is the purpose of putting all this in a separate class instead of using `OfType` directly, or writing an extension method that enhances its functionality? Seems like a pain to instantiate a class just to filter a list.

Comment: One other thing is that in approach2 you don't actually need the Cast due to covariance. ie `IEnumerable<Derived>` can be assigned to `IEnumerable<Base>`

Comment: Approach 2 is fine, as it use generics all the way , is verifiable at compile time, there's not much difference between 2 & 3, but its preferred to have generic class or generic method, you are mixing both in Approach 3 and it doesn't have the constraint for the `TResult`

Comment: Looking at constraints should the constraint in 2 be `TResult : T`?

Comment: @Chris I had not realised OfType<Base> returns derived classes. That could be really interesting if I would like to filter sub-families of a base class. It could also potentially cause problems if I want a specific type, which has derived classes. Anyhow that really good to keep in mind.

Comment: @RikDIf it returning subtypes causes problems then you probably have a design problem. If I ask for all things of type animal then I should expect to get dogs and cats back. If I'm doing something that breaks with dogs or cats then that method isn't really actually working on animals at all...

Comment: @Chris If I change the constraint to TResult : T I can indeed change Approach 2 to return entities.OfType<TResult>();

Comment: @JohnWu It allows me to do things like ICriteria<User> criteria = new AndCriteria<User>(new DisplayNameContains("bla"), new EmailAddressContains(".com"), new TypeOfCriteria<User, AdminUser>());

Comment: @Chris if puppies derive from dogs and kittens from cats, if I want to filter on cats and not get kittens, TypeOf<Cat> would also return kittens, correct? I agree violating LSP is a design problem, but I don't think that's the case. It was pure theoretical anyway. I'm not a fan of big inheritance trees.

Comment: I would not derive puppies from dogs or kittens from cats. A puppy is just an instance of a dog, and a kitten is just an instance of a cat. Filter by age.

Comment: I like approach 3, because it is easy to read.

Comment: @RikD: Yes, you would get kittens too. But as I say if you wanted cats that weren't kittens then there is a problem in your design but as you say that isn't a problem in your current described structure. My point is that I would consider `foo.GetType()==type` to be a code smell and 99% of the time wrong (possibly 100% but only sith deal in absolutes).

Comment: Sometime the anti pattern is king,just because you can do cool stuff doesn't mean you should, why not just pass the type of user into the filter, no generics, easy to read and adapt later. seems like over kill for something which should be simple. Without the full context of why this is smarter, its hard to say either way, well at least for me.

Comment: @RikD I still have the same question. What is the purpose of putting all that in separate classes instead of using `Where` or custom extension methods? Postfix binary operations are harder to read, and your solution requires a new class and interface for every new criterion.